# Prolog, counting from an interval; (SWI-PROLOG)

Tags: count, prolog, intervals

I have a small question. I need to make a predicate that counts from a natural number to some other natural number. I have to implement a check too, that the second interval is bigger than the first one. However I got stuck during my way.

Here is my code (SWI-PROLOG)

```
count(O, _, O).
count(A, B, C) :- count(A, B, D), C is D+1, C =< B.
```

It works kind of well as, I can get the results `C=1, C=2, C=3, C=4` if I type in `count(1, 4, C).` However I get stuck at the end, it will result in an error with stack overflow.

The question is how do I make it to stop? I have tried almost everything. =(

Thanks for your response!

Answer (score 3):

SWI-Prolog has a builtin for that...

```
?- help(between).
between(+Low, +High, ?Value)
    Low  and High are  integers, High >=Low.   If  Value is an  integer,
    Low=< Value=< High.   When Value  is a  variable it is  successively
    bound  to  all integers  between  Low and  High.    If High  is  inf
    or  infinite between/3 is  true iff Value>= Low,  a feature that  is
    particularly  interesting  for generating  integers from  a  certain
    value.

true.

?- between(1, 4, Value).
Value = 1 ;
Value = 2 ;
Value = 3 ;
Value = 4.

?-
```

Answer (score 1):

As [Paulo Moura](https://stackoverflow.com/users/634629/paulo-moura) pointed out, re-ordering will solve part of the problem. Getting it to terminate gracefully, may be achieved by adding an additional clause to handle the recursive terminating condition.

Try this.

```
countAtoB(A,B,A) :-
    A =:= B, !.

countAtoB(A,B,A) :-
    A < B.

countAtoB(A,B,I) :- 
    A < B, 
    X is A+1,  
    countAtoB(X,B,I).
```

Queries would then look like this. For the sake of comparison, I have repeated the same set of test queries using **between/3**, strait after.

```
?- countAtoB(1,4,I).
I = 1 ;
I = 2 ;
I = 3 ;
I = 4.

?- countAtoB(4,4,I).
I = 4.

?- countAtoB(4,1,I).
false.

?- countAtoB(4,1,1000).
false.

?- between(1,4,I).
I = 1 ;
I = 2 ;
I = 3 ;
I = 4.

?- between(4,4,I).
I = 4.

?- between(4,1,I).
false.

?- between(4,1,1000).
false.

?-
```

Comment: `countAtoB(9,1,I).` succeeds. That does not make much sense.

Comment: `countAtoB(9,1,1000).` succeeds as well.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out. It never occurred to me to check invalid arguments. I've reviewed my post and made the appropriate corrections.

Answer (score 0):

This

```
count(A, B, C) :- count(A, B, D), ...
```

causes an infinite recursion.

Just reorder the predicate, like this:

```
count(A, B, A) :- A =< B.
count(A, B, C) :- A < B, A2 is A+1, count(A2, B, C).
```